# module 'pytest' has no attribute 'allure'

Tags: python, selenium, allure

I am getting the error "AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'allure' in the below code

```
def take_screenshots(txt):

file_name = "{}.png".format(Communication.get_random_characters())

Settings.get_driver().get_screenshot_as_file(file_name)
    pytest.allure.attach.file(file_name,name=txt,attachment_type=pytest.allure.attachment_type.PNG)
```

> E AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'allure'

I am using the below plugins for the project and the python version is the latest one: 3.9.7

```
pytest-allure=2.9.44
allure-python-commons=2.9.44
apipkg==2.0.1
attrs==21.2.0
certifi==2021.10.8
chardet==4.0.0
colorama==0.4.4
enum34==1.1.10
execnet==1.9.0
idna==3.2
lxml==4.6.3
namedlist==1.8
pluggy==1.0.0
py==1.8.2
pytest==6.2.5
pytest-forked==1.3.0
pytest-xdist==2.3.0
python-guerrillamail==0.2.0
requests==2.26.0
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.26.7
imaplib2==3.6
paramiko==2.7.2
pandas==1.3.3
xlrd==2.0.1
cryptography==35.0.0
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
bs4==0.0.1
pytest-timeout==1.4.2
xmltodict==0.12.0
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not installed the `Allure-pytest` package. you have to install it in your project using the below command.

```
pip install allure-pytest
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But after installing the "allure-pytest" in my project. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I have removed  pytest. from "pytest.allure.attach.file" and it begins to work. It seems to be issue due to pytest namespace deprecation.